# How to keep test coverage high when mocking?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Let's say I have this object which is a core part of my system, and most of its work is to communicate with a remote agent - send tasks and get responses:

```
class AgentAPI:
    ... # Constructor etc.

    def do_foo(self, args):
        .... # Send data and wait for response
        return result

    def do_bar(self, args):
        .... # Send data and wait for response
        return result
```

The way I would go about unit-testing this object is with a mock, right?
So:

```
def test_agent_api_foo():
    agent_api = AgentAPI(someargs)
    agent_api.do_foo = Mock()
    .... # test logic
```

That means the methods are not really executed, of course...

So how do I keep my unit-tests reliable on highly distributed systems?

Comment: By unittesting each unit, and by creating integration tests that actually use remote agents (you don't actually need a physical network for that, a connection to localhost suffices).

Comment: It sounds like you would like to test that `do_foo` and `do_bar` take their parameters and compose something, send it somewhere else, possibly manipulate the result and return it. That sounds like there is code there worth testing. You should mock out the destination with something which accepts this data and returns a fake response. It looks like the name of the test: `test_agent_api` means that you really want to test the methods of `AgentAPI`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that sounds good, but what if the agents and the server are not compatible for this simple integration test (different os/dependencies/language etc.) ? Should I set up a whole environment + automate the procedure just for the tests? Or is it a better practice to create a new fake "agent" that the AgentAPI object will communicate with (and always keep it updated too) like quamrana said?

Comment: @user3134477: not using the actual server, replacing it with some kind of mocked service or recorded network-level communication, carries the risk that your test harness becomes outdated. I'd investigate investing in making the server runnable in the same environment, be it natively or with a VM. A different language or dependency should not be too big a hurdle; it is just a subprocess of your integration test.

Comment: @user3134477: so yes, automate the process for your tests! Testing is a long-term investment; how long is this system going to be under development?

Comment: If this really is a *unit* test then you must not use the network or filesystem. However, if this is really an *integration* test then I think you *should* go out to the network, but to a test server, so you won't need to apply mocks to any code under test.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sounds doable, thanks :)